# Explicitly declaring abstract base class

Tags: c++, abstract-class

Is there a way to explicitly declare a base class as abstract in C++?

I know that I can create a pure virtual function in the class which will implicitly declare a class as abstract. However, I don't want to have to create a dummy function just to define in in derived classes.

I could also make the constructor protected, which would prevent the instantiation of the object, but that doesn't actually mark the class as abstract.

So, is there a way to do this? (I am using C++11, if that added a way to do this, but I didn't find anything that looked right)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can make the destructor pure-virtual. Since you always need a destructor, there's no additional mental cost:

```
struct Foo
{
    virtual ~Foo() = 0;
};

inline Foo::~Foo() { }
```

(You do of course need an implementation of the destructor, so you have to provide one out-of-line.)

You can still make the destructor `protected`, which is good practice following the "make non-leaf classes abstract" rule.

Example:

```
struct Bar : Foo  { };

// Foo f;  // Error, Foo is abstract
Bar b;     // OK
```

Comment: Woah, that works? As in, the `Foo` deconstructor will still be called when `Bar` is deconstructed?

Comment: @Xymostech: Naturally :-) (You can provide definitions for *any* pure-virtual function.)

Comment: Interesting. It looks like Clang gives a warning: `note: unimplemented pure virtual method '~Foo' in 'Foo'` when you do try to create a `Foo`, but it works great!

Comment: In regards to my previous comment, the compilation does fail because `Foo` is abstract, but it also gives that warning.

Answer (score 1):

I like Kerrek's answer. That way the class cannot be instantiated and therefore is abstract.

However, it still isn't obviously clear that the class is abstract unless you scan through the entire declaration of the class and see that the destructor is virtual.

Another idea I had is you could create a pre-processor definition for the word "abstract" using `#define`. This way you could do something like the following:

```
abstract struct Foo {};
```

which would be no different than

```
struct Foo {};
```

The problem I see with this is that this doesn't force the class to be abstract, so you could use a macro to also declare the virtual destructor. Something like:

```
#define ABSTRACT_CLASS(class_name) \
  class class_name { \
    virtual ~class_name() = 0; //
```

And then use it like so:

```
ABSTRACT_CLASS(Foo) {
  // class declaration
};
```

Which would be turned into:

```
class foo {
  virtual ~class_name() = 0; // {
  // class declaration
};
```

Disclaimer: My macro might be slightly off. I'm not sure if it'll actually paste class_name with the ~ and the () touching the variable name. Also, I'm not sure if I'd do this myself, it's not the most beautiful solution, especially commenting out the brace since that wouldn't work if you put it on the next line. But you asked how you could mark something as abstract and I gave it to you!

Answer (score 0):

> Is there a way to explicitly declare a base class as abstract in C++?

No, there is not.  A class is abstract only if it has at least one abstract method declared in it.  If you do not want your base class to be instantiated directly, then a protected constructor is a good choice.